# Change Background Color in map function, react js and javascript project

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
const colorList = [
    '#FF6263',
    '#DE4839',
    '#BF3325',
    '#E21717',
    '#BF3312',
    '#D82E2F',
    '#EB4D4B',
    '#EF5354',
    '#B4161B',
    '#E6425E',
    '#E83A59',
    '#B9345A']

        <Row flex="flex">
        {colorList.map((data, index) =>{
            const dat = `'${data}'`
            console.log(`'${data}'`)
            return(
                <Col key={index} style={{
                    width: '50px',
                    height: '200px',
                    backgroundColor: {dat}
                }}>
                    <p>{data}</p>
                </Col>
            )
        })}
        </Row>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips on how to ask a question that won't attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using back-ticks that's why don't need to use single quotation(**''**);

**Change 1-**

Should be-

```
`const dat = `${data}`;
```

Instead of

```
const dat = `'${data}'`
```

**Change 2-**

Should be

```
style={{
        width: '50px',
        height: '200px',
        backgroundColor: dat
      }}
```

Instead of

```
style={{
         width: '50px',
         height: '200px',
         backgroundColor: {dat}
      }}
```

**Improved**:

```
<Row flex="flex">
        {colorList.map((data, index) =>{
            const dat = `${data}`;
            console.log(`${data}`);
            return(
                <Col key={index} style={{
                    width: '50px',
                    height: '200px',
                    backgroundColor: dat
                }}>
                    <p>{data}</p>
                </Col>
            )
        })}
        </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing color like
backgroundColor: "'#someColor'"

Edit this line

```
const dat = `'${data}'`
```

To

```
const dat = `${data}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Another best way of mapping is this:

```
  const colorList = [
    { color: "#FF6263" },
    { color: "#DE4839" },
    { color: "#BF3325" },
    { color: "#E21717" },
    { color: "#BF3312" },
    { color: "#D82E2F" },
    { color: "#EB4D4B" },
    { color: "#EF5354" },
    { color: "#B4161B" },
    { color: "#E6425E" },
    { color: "#E83A59" },
    { color: "#B9345A" },
  ];
      <Row flex="flex">
        {colorList.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <Col
              key={index}
              style={{
                width: "50px",
                height: "200px",
                backgroundColor: `${data.color}`,
              }}
            >
              <p>{data.color}</p>
            </Col>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
```